# How to get nested value from within an object using a string without using multiple brackets?

Tags: javascript

Put differently can I do this somehow: `obj['data.users.admins.dashboard[3]']`

I could create a simple function and parse string then call the object. But I want to know what's possible first as there would lot of edge case, nontrivial.

above would be same as

`obj['data']['users']['amdins']['dashboard'][3]`

Comment: Does `obj[data.users.admins.dashboard[3]]` (without the quotes) not do what you intend?

Comment: updating the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lodash get https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
```

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L3028 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with some clever usage of `split()` and `reduce()`:

```js
const obj = { data : { users: { admins: { dashboard: [1, 2, 3, 4] } } } };
const path = 'data.users.admins.dashboard[3]';

const result = path.replace(/\[/g,'.').replace(/\]/g,'').split('.')
                   .reduce((obj,key) => obj && obj[key], obj);

console.log(result);
```

How?

1. Replace array accessors like `[3]` with just `.3` -> `data.users.admins.dashboard.3`
2. Split string on periods -> `['data', 'users', 'admins', 'dashboard', '3']`
3. `reduce` over the array accessing each key if the previous one was valid

Here's the snippet in a helper function:

```js
function getByPath(obj, path) {
  return path.replace(/\[/g, '.').replace(/\]/g, '').split('.').reduce((obj, key) => obj && obj[key], obj);
}

//sample usage
console.log(getByPath({thing: [1, 2]}, "thing[0]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using `eval`, but `eval` is EVIL. Use it at your own risk!

```js
const data = { users: { admins: { dashboard: [1, 2, 3, 4] } } };

eval('data.users.admins.dashboard[3]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Proxy`:

```
const obj = new Proxy({
  data: {
    users: {
      admins: {
        dashboard: [10, 21, 31, 41],
      }
    }
  },
}, {
  get: function (map, key, receiver) {
    try {
      return eval(`map.${key}`)
    } catch (error) {
      return undefined;
    };
  },
});


obj['data.users.admins.dashboard[3]'] // 41
obj['erter.sdfdsfds.admins.sdfsdf[3]'] // undefined
```

In normal objects it would throw an error can't read property of undefined == better than regular objects in js :)

Updated:

https://repl.it/repls/HarmlessMessyCommas

```
const obj = new Proxy({
  data: {
    users: {
      admins: {
        dashboard: [10, 21, 31, 41, {
          hi: 'I am hi'
        }],
      }
    }
  },
}, {
  get: function (map, key, receiver) {

    try {

      let splitedKey = key.split(".");
      let current = map;

      while (splitedKey.length > 0) {
        let newValue = splitedKey.shift();

        let openingBracketIndex = newValue.lastIndexOf("[");
        let arrIndex = Number(newValue.slice(openingBracketIndex + 1, newValue.length - 1));
        let isArr = !isNaN(arrIndex)

        if (openingBracketIndex > -1 && newValue[newValue.length - 1] === "]" && isArr) {
          let arrName = newValue.slice(0, openingBracketIndex);
          current = current[arrName][arrIndex];
        } else {
          current = current[newValue];
        }

      }

      return current;
    } catch (error) {
      return undefined;
    };
  },
});


console.log(obj['data.users.admins.dashboard[3]'] == 41);
console.log(obj['data.users.admins.dashboard[0]'] == 10);
console.log(obj["data.users.admins.dashboard[4].hi"] === "I am hi");
console.log(obj['erter.sdfdsfds.admins.sdfsdf[3]'] === undefined)
```

It works **but** not perfectly, especially with nested arrays are not going to work b/c even a human wouldn't know if someone is trying to access a property name or array, ex:

```
const map = {
  "dashboard[1]": 'i am string',
  "dashboard": [1, 2],
}
```

So if someone wrote `map.dashboard[1]` so it is going to return "2" instead of "i am string" b/c if condition for array is above the else condition (else condition = if not array)

I hope it helps :)

Comment: if you're going to use eval, then you don't need a proxy. `obj = {a:{b:{c:1}}};
path = 'a.b.c';
eval(\`obj.${path}\`);`

Comment: yes you are correct, but then you would have to use eval each time you are getting the value from object. Also you can change eval to regular code as well -- updated the answer @MuhammadUmer